# Multiple and or condition in ifelse statement in R, getting unexpected output

Tags: r

I have a data frame of multiple columns. I want to create a new column based on conditions as follows:

if both colA and colB > 0 or both colA and colB < 0; colC woulb be "Yes" else colC would be "No".

I was trying to use `ifelse` statement in R to create a new column as follows:

```
leadsnp4$ConcordEffect=ifelse(leadsnp4[paste0('Z_recalculated_in_',trait1)] > 0 & leadsnp4[paste0('Z_recalculated_in_',trait2)] > 0,'Yes',
                              ifelse(leadsnp4[paste0('Z_recalculated_in_',trait1)] < 0 & leadsnp4[paste0('Z_recalculated_in_',trait2)] < 0,
                              'Yes','No'))
```

`trait1` and `trait2` are string variables (`trait1='DEP', trait2='BMI'`).

But this is giving me a list of two:

```
> str(leadsnp4$ConcordEffect)
 chr [1:43, 1] "No" "Yes" "No" "Yes" "No" "Yes" "No" "No" "No" "Yes" "Yes" "No" "No" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "No" "No" "Yes" "No" "No" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:43] "5" "10" "23" "31" ...
  ..$ : chr "Z_recalculated_in_DEP"
```

What I am doing wrong here? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[` to subset the dataframe. Using `[` returns a dataframe back.

Here's a simple reproducible example to demonstrate the issue.

This is what you have -

```
df <- head(mtcars)
col <- 'cyl'
df$res <- ifelse(df[col] ==6, 'yes', 'no')
str(df$res)

#chr [1:6, 1] "yes" "yes" "no" "yes" "no" "yes"
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:6] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" #...
#  ..$ : chr "cyl"
```

Solution -

```
df <- head(mtcars)
col <- 'cyl'
df$res <- ifelse(df[[col]] ==6, 'yes', 'no')
str(df$res)
#chr [1:6] "yes" "yes" "no" "yes" "no" "yes"
```